# Extracting positive/negative floating-point numbers from a string

Tags: text-processing, sed, numeric-data

I am trying to extract numbers out of some text. Currently I am using the following:

```
echo "2.5 test. test -50.8" | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/[^0-9.]/ /g' -e 's/^ *//g' -e 's/ *$//g' | tr -s ' '
```

This would give me 2.5, "." and 50.8. How should I modify the first `sed` so it would detect float numbers, both positive and negative?

Comment: Should the solution also be able to handle integers (positive and negative) as well as numbers in 1e10 format?

Comment: No, just negative and positive floats would be fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`grep` works well for this:

```
$ echo "2.5 test. test -50.8" | grep -Eo '[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?'
2.5
-50.8
```

#### How it works

- `-E`

  Use extended regex.
- `-o`

  Return only the matches, not the context
- `[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?+`

  Match numbers which are identified as:

  - `[+-]?`

    An optional leading sign
  - `[0-9]+`

    One or more numbers
  - `([.][0-9]+)?`

    An optional period followed by one or more numbers.

#### Getting the output on one line

```
$ echo "2.5 test. test -50.8" | grep -Eo '[+-]?[0-9]+([.][0-9]+)?' | tr '\n' ' '; echo ""
2.5 -50.8
```

Comment: Great, thanks for detailed explanation. Is it possible to get returned values all in one line rather than each on a new line? Cause I want append the result of this to an existing file.

Comment: Your welcome.  And, yes, one line is possible.  See update.

Comment: Try it with `1.2.3` (results in `1.2` and `3`)  or `9-9` (results in `9` and `-9`)...

Answer (score 3):

A `grep` solution:

```
$ echo "2.5 test. test -50.8" | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -E '^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?([0-9]+)$'
2.5
-50.8
```

- The `tr` just converts the line into multiple lines by replacing the spaces with newlines.
- The `grep` command looks for strings that starts with an optional `+` or `-`, possibly followed by some digits and an optional decimal point. Then we require some digits at the end.

This will let through things like `00000123.91288000`, which just looks strange. Is this a number we want to filter out or not? It's technically a floating point number, just oddly formatted.

**EDIT**: To *properly* check for numbers, do *not* write your own regular expression!  Use a library routine from somewhere reliable.

In my case, I would use Perl's `Scalar::Util` package, which has a convenient `looks_like_number()` subroutine:

```
$ echo "2.5 test. test -50.8" | tr ' ' '\n' | perl -MScalar::Util -ne 'Scalar::Util::looks_like_number($_) && print'
2.5
-50.8
```

This has the added benefit of finding numbers on other forms, such as `1e3`.

Comment: Try your solutions with `First number is 1.2. Second is 2.4.`  (Yes, there are many special cases:  Without further guidance on the input, it is hard to decide how each special case should be treated.)

Comment: @John1024 Touché, you're correct there.

Comment: It is good to have alternatives, so +1.