# how to select a number inside a string with bash?

Tags: bash

I have a string like:

```
      <td>8.2º C</td>
```

with line break at the beginning.

How can I select only the value `8.2`, so that it gives me as output:

```
8.2
```

Comment: See for example the following Q&A https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290978

Comment: Where do you have this data? In a variable or in a file? Is it an XML file?

Comment: Yuck, whatever produces your data should be fixed. The character there is the masculine ordinal indicator (U+00BA), not the degree sign (U+00B0), and the space is in the wrong place. It should be like so: `8 °C`

Comment: it's a web scraper

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the unwanted set of characters with the `tr` command.

```
$ fred='<td>8.2º C</td>'
$ echo ${fred} |tr -d \<\>a-zA-Z\ \/\º
8.2
```

Comment: In this case, since we know what we want to _keep_, get rid of the complement of that: `tr -dc '0-9.'`

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I wanted to do, but couldn't remember -c compement. :-)